# Google Bigquery multiple updates based on WHERE - need a solution

Tags: where-clause, updates, google-bigquery

is there a way to do multiple updates based on other field value
 WHERE, not CASE

idea is below

thanks

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE dataset.people
SET CBSA_CODE = '54620' where substr(zip,1,5) = '99047',
SET CBSA_CODE = '31793' where substr(zip,1,5) = '45700'
```

Comment: what is wrong with CASE to be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CASE` expression is in fact the typical way you would handle this logic:

```
UPDATE dataset.people
SET CBSA_CODE = CASE SUBSTR(zip, 1, 5)
                    WHEN '99047' THEN '54620'
                    WHEN '45700' THEN '31793' END
WHERE
    SUBSTR(zip, 1, 5) IN ('99047', '45700');
```

The only alternative to this which I can see would be to run mutliple update statements, one for each ZIP code value.  But that seems unwieldy and undesirable as compared to using a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL CASE, which is part of Standard SQL (see [official BQ docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions)):

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE dataset.people
SET CBSA_CODE = CASE
  WHEN substr(zip,1,5) = '99047' THEN '54620'
  WHEN substr(zip,1,5) = '45700' THEN '31793'
END
WHERE substr(zip,1,5) IN('99047', '45700')
```

Comment: [Here is a link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions) to the documentation.