# Google Bigquery UPDATE row takes too long - need a improve performance solution

Tags: sql-update, google-bigquery

this update  takes 194 seconds for 220mln rows.
Is there a way to improve that?

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE dataset.people SET CBSA_CODE = '54620' where substr(zip,1,5) = '99047'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking for performance help, it is useful to include a screenshot of the Execution Plan from the BigQuery UI to see which stages are the most intensive, and where the time was spent. Without that, though, I suspect that this small optimization should help:

```
UPDATE dataset.people SET CBSA_CODE = '54620' WHERE zip LIKE '99047%'
```

BigQuery should be able to push this filter down to its storage system, since it's a more natural way to express string containment, so if you see a high "Read" time in the Execution Plan for the original query, this might reduce it.

Comment: doing multiupdate, so LIKE% would not work, but for sinle update this is better!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105187/google-bigquery-multiple-updates-based-on-where-need-a-solution